# Using rpy2 to return image data from R to Python

Tags: python, r, imagemagick, rpy2

I'm creating a plot in R, but then trying to return the resulting image data to Python so that Python can display the image.

Within R, I've used the `magick` library to [hold the image in memory](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#Read_and_write) (instead of plotting to the screen).

> "We use `image_write` to export an image in any format to a file on disk, or in memory if `path = NULL`"

I'm unsure how to process either the `SexpExtPtr` or `ByteVector` types that are returned by `rpy2` to Python.

```py
import rpy2.robjects as ro

r = ro.r

r('''
    library("magick")
    figure <- image_graph(width = 400, height = 400, res = 96)
    plot(c(1,2,3))
    image <- image_write(figure, path = NULL, format = "png")
    # image_write(figure, path = 'example.png', format = 'png')
''')

figure = ro.globalenv['figure']
image = ro.globalenv['image']

im = Image.open(BytesIO(image))
```

The code above gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 23, in <module>
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(image))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'ByteVector'
```

In Python:

- `figure` has type `<class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpExtPtr'>`
- `image` has type `<class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.ByteVector'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... it turns out that `<class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.ByteVector'>` is an iterable and I can use `bytes()` to construct an array of bytes.

Also, by putting the code inside a function that uses `return` to return the PIL image I can get the image to display within a Jupyter notebook (alternatively we could just do `image.show()`)

```
from io import BytesIO

import PIL.Image as Image
import rpy2.robjects as ro

def main():
    r = ro.r

    r('''
        library("magick")
        figure <- image_graph(width = 400, height = 400, res = 96)
        plot(c(1,2,3))
        image <- image_write(figure, path = NULL, format = "png")
        image_write(figure, path = 'example.png', format = 'png')
    ''')

    image_data = ro.globalenv['image']

    image = Image.open(BytesIO(bytes(image_data)))

    return image


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = main()
    image.show()
```

Comment: rpy2 makes all R list, vectors, arrays iterable from Python. In addition to that few array types are compatible across R and Python and for them more efficient solutions exist. For example, your object `image` will implement the numpy array interface (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.interface.html). This will let you use C acceleration with compatible package (e.g., `numpy.array`, or `numpy.asarray`).